# How can I sort by a different column if first choice is null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a movie database. I want to sort by released date but when `released` date is missing (null or empty) i want to sort by `dateAdded` instead

```
SELECT 
    movie.ID,
    Title,
    released,
    dateAdded
FROM
    movie
WHERE
    dateAdded is not null 
    and (released <= CURDATE() or released is null or released ='')
ORDER BY released DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: What type of column is `released`? If it's `DATE` not sure how it could be empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you do it like this:

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(released, dateAdded)
```

That's somewhat abusive since it can't be indexed properly but will work on relatively large amounts of data without bogging down too badly.

Comment: @code578841441: you specify `ASC` or `DESC` after the expression. In this case, *after* the closing paren of the IFNULL function.

Comment: Right, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the proprietary `ISNULL` you better use Standard SQL's `COALESCE`:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(released, dateAdded) DESC
```

Comment: `IFNULL` is a more obvious label, but you're right, [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) is more standard.